# Doctrine / DQL get the entities having the exactly the same related entities

Tags: php, doctrine, dql

Imagine i have a entity `Person` which has a many-to-many relation with `Vehicle`

How can i find another Person exactly having the same Vehicles?

Example:

Person 1 (ID=1) has vehicle with id 5,6 and 7

Person 2 (ID=2) has vehicles with id 5,6,8 -> should not match with person 1!

Person 3 (ID=3) has vehicle with id 5 ->should not match with person 1!

Person 4 (ID=4) has vehicles with id 5,6 and 7 -> should match with person 1

Person 5 (ID=5) has vehicles with id 5,6 and 7 -> should match with person 1 and person 4

So what is the DQL expression for that?

I tried already with "IN" but this will also match even if just one of my id's match.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Clean `DQL`**:

```
$query = $entityManager->createQuery("
  SELECT p, pv 
    FROM Person p
    INNER JOIN p.vehicles pv 
    WHERE pv.id in (
      SELECT v.id
        FROM Vehicle v
        INNER JOIN v.persons vp
        WHERE p.id <> vp.id
    ) GROUP BY p.id
    HAVING count(pv.id) > 1");
$persons = $query->getResult();
```

**Explanation**:
To get persons with same vehicles, you need to get vehicles, that equal to person's, but attached to other. `HAVING` regulates count of minimal same vehicles, by which we group persons in collection.

You can use more flexible approach with `PHP`, that get only persons with full identical vehicles. Steps:

1. get all persons with vehicles
2. compare vehicles Ids
3. add to result only persons IDs with the same vehicles
4. get collection of persons with same vehicles

**Code**:

```
<?php

$query = $entityManager->createQuery("select p,v from Person p JOIN p.vehicles v");
$persons = $query->getArrayResult();

$personsIdsWithSameVehicles = [];

foreach ($persons as $person) {
    $vehiclesIds = array_column($person['vehicles'], 'id');
    $subPersons = array_filter($persons, function($filterPerson) use ($person) {
       if($filterPerson['id'] != $person['id']) return $filterPerson;
    });

    foreach ($subPersons as $subPerson) {
        $subVehiclesIds = array_column($subPerson['vehicles'], 'id');
        if(count($vehiclesIds) == count($subVehiclesIds) and
            empty(array_diff($vehiclesIds, $subVehiclesIds))) {

            $personsIdsWithSameVehicles[] = $person['id'];
            break;

        }
    }
}

$personsQuery = $entityManager->createQuery("select p from Person p where p.id IN(:persons)");
$personsQuery->setParameter('persons', $personsIdsWithSameVehicles);
$personsWithSameVehicles = $personsQuery->getResult();
```